# How to Stack an Image with Text

Tags: html, css, list

Does anyone know how to stack an image and text below it? I'm pretty sure you can do it like you would a list-kind of like the way you'd set up a nav.
Similar to: http://www.invisionapp.com/customers
I'm trying to copy the code, but my text just goes on until it's done.
I want an image and text to be in one bullet point and then move onto the next bullet point. Thanks.

HTML:

```
<div class="photolist">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="C:\Users\Mitchel\Desktop\Dreamweaver\images\mymap.JPG" height="20%" width="20%">
        <blockquote>An F-22 Raptor and P-38 Lightning fly side-by-sideover Lake Michigan</blockquote></li>
        <li><img src="C:\Users\Mitchel\Desktop\Dreamweaver\images\mymap.JPG" height="20%" width="20%">
        <blockquote>An F-22 Raptor and P-38 Lightning fly side-by-sideover Lake Michigan</blockquote></li>
        <li><img src="C:\Users\Mitchel\Desktop\Dreamweaver\images\mymap.JPG" height="20%" width="20%">
        <blockquote>An F-22 Raptor and P-38 Lightning fly side-by-sideover Lake Michigan</blockquote></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.photolist{
    position:relative;
    top:80px;
    margin-left:10%;
    background-color:none;
}
.photolist ul {
    display: inline;
}
.photolist li{
    display: inline;
    margin: 2px 10px;
}
blockquote{
    width:inherit;
    display:inline;
    text-align:left;
}
```

Comment: i dont know which part of the linked site your talking about, and what you are trying to do

Comment: I think your problem is `display: inline;`, try just removing it.

Comment: Muhammad: I'm looking below the video where they show the logo, a blockquote, and an image of the person who said the quote. See Yammer, Treehouse, SoundCloud, etc.

Comment: Remove `display: inline` from `blockquote` and apply `li > * { display: block;}`

Answer (score 0):

Setting the image to `display:block` and letting the `blockquote` be it's default block level is more than enough.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.photolist {
  margin-left: 10%;
}
.photolist ul {
  display: inline-block;
}
.photolist li {
  display: block;
  margin: 2px 10px;
}
blockquote {}
```

```html
<div class="photolist">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/city/1" height="20%" width="20%" />
      <blockquote>An F-22 Raptor and P-38 Lightning fly side-by-sideover Lake Michigan</blockquote>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/city/2" height="20%" width="20%" />
      <blockquote>An F-22 Raptor and P-38 Lightning fly side-by-sideover Lake Michigan</blockquote>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/city/3" height="20%" width="20%" />
      <blockquote>An F-22 Raptor and P-38 Lightning fly side-by-sideover Lake Michigan</blockquote>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I'm not sure that a `blockquote` is really semantic here.

> The blockquote element represents a section that is quoted from another source.
>
> Content inside a blockquote must be quoted from another source, whose address, if it has one, may be cited in the cite attribute.

I might consider using a `figure/figcaption` inside the `li`...feels more correct to me.

> The figure element represents some flow content, optionally with a caption, that is self-contained and is typically referenced as a single unit from the main flow of the document.
>
> The figure element can be used to annotate illustrations, diagrams, photos, code listings, etc., that are referenced in the main content of the document, but that could, without affecting the flow of the document, be moved away from that primary content — e.g., to the side of the page, to dedicated pages, or to an appendix.